# CSS transition on an initially hidden elemement

Tags: css, css-transitions

I would like to make a css transition on an element which has `display: none` set. Consider the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CSS Transition From Hidden</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            div {
                -webkit-transition-property: all;
                -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
            }       

            div.hidden {
                display: none;
                opacity: 0;
            }    

            div.from {
                opacity: 0;
            }
        </style>     

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loaded() {
                var e = document.getElementById("foo");
                e.className = "from";
                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(function(t) {
                    e.className = null;
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="loaded()">
        <div id="foo" class="hidden">
            My test div
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to go from `class="div.hidden"` to `class=""`, i.e. from `display: none; opacity: 0;` to `display: block; opacity: 1;` However, in chrome (at least) an object that has `display: none` does not animate. The element goes to the end state immediately.

My work around for this is to first set the element to `display: block; opacity: 0;` and then do the transition in the next frame (using `requestAnimationFrame()`. It is kind of awkward, and I can't find any explanation for this behavior in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/). I know that I could use the `visibility`-attribute, but I don't want to use it because I don't want to layout the hidden element.

So, the questions are: Is this the correct behavior or a bug? If it is the correct behavior, is there a better way to write the code? Note that I'm not asking if there are any libraries that can do it, I want to know if there is a better way to do it directly on the DOM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding the question on if this is in the spec, there is an interesting thread on the www-style@w3.org list [here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Dec/0353.html). I haven't read it all but it seems as they don't start animations from `none` and that the transition spec needs to clarify that as well.

**Update**: I have asked the mail list and I got this link to the [minutes](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Jan/0099.html) of a work group meeting where it was decided that there should be no transition if the start state is `display: none`.

To make sure that the transition is performed you must make sure that the value of the animated property is calculated before it is set to its new target. Values are normally not calculated when display is set to none. Here is a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <title>Fade</title>

    <style>
      .hidden { display: none }
      .start { opacity: 0 }
      .transition { opacity: 1; -webkit-transition: opacity 1s }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='div' class="hidden">Test</div>

    <script>
      var elem = document.getElementById('div');

      function ontransitionend(event) {
        elem.className = null;
        elem.removeEventListener('transitionend', ontransitionend);
      }
      elem.addEventListener('transitionend', ontransitionend);

      elem.className = 'start';
      window.getComputedStyle(elem).opacity;
      elem.className = 'transition';
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that you have to access the opacity property. It is not enough to call `getComputedStyle()`!

Answer (score 2):

You should not necessarily relay on `transitionend` callbacks. 
To show with a transition on the opacity property (or others) an hidden element that initially has `display:none`, simply use inline style to set `display:block` then remove your CSS class `.hidden` to animate the element as you want:

CSS:

```
#foo {
    display: none;
    opacity: 1;
    /*optional, other ending properties...*/
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    /*optional, other starting properties...*/
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="foo" class="hidden">
    My test div
</div>
```

finally, the javascript part to show the element with a transition:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('foo');
elem.style.display = 'block';
elem.classList.remove('hidden');
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several css properties that cannot be incremented in small steps (what is the value of `display` 25% of the way between `none` and `block`?), particularly those that have non numeric values. The workaround you are describing is pretty much the standard way of dealing with this. jQuery, for example, uses something similar in its `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods.

If you want to animate the transition from taking up no space to standard layout, you can transition the `height` and `width` properties.

Comment: I'm not saying that there should be an animation on the `display` property. I'm setting `display` to block and (in this case) the `opacity` is changed. This is the way transitions work. The properties you list in `transition-property` are animated, the rest are set immediately. Why is it different for `display`?

Comment: No, it is not that I don't want it to take no space. It should take very little time. And the hidden elements can be quite many and complex (slide show).

Comment: @TobiasRitzau Do you mean opacity is set immediately?

Comment: Yes, instead of a 2s fade in, opacity is set to 1 directly.

Comment: @TobiasRitzau If you remove the `display:none` and use exactly the same code for only opacity, does it work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

the display: none  mean that you could reach the element but first you should make sure that 
element has been rendered . 
you can use ready function in jquery or implemente it in javascript to make sure that the element is there .
you could do the above by using : javascript(use timer to increase the opacity) or jquery as below

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CSS Transition From Hidden</title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css">

            div.hidden {
                display: none;
                opacity: 0;
            }    

                    </style>     

        <script type="text/javascript">
$.ready = function () {

                $("#foo").fadeIn(2000);

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="foo" class="hidden">
            My test div
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The element is there. That is not the issue. Sure I can use libraries, but I wonder if there is a better way to implement it directly on the DOM. I will clarify that in the question.

Comment: yes , you can create timer in javascript to increase the opacity

Comment: But, how is that better? (Compatibility is not an issue in this case)

Comment: yes , its Compatibile as we will change the class of the div inside the timer

Comment: That's not how you use jQuery ready (it's a function, not a property). And this is not using CSS transitions.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and i dont think it should be considered an acceptable behavior by the browsers. The problem is not that anyone is trying to animate the actual display property. Its that you cannot have an element with display: none, update the property to inline or whatever and then animate the opacity for example, not even if you put a timeout for 10 seconds after the display has been updated.

My workaround right now is putting width and height to 0, overflow to hidden, updating these values and THEN update the animation attributes. At least it behaves more similar to display none than visibility hidden.

Answer (score 0):

display:none jacks up the animation. It's a shame and I think should be addressed by browsers. I've gotten around the problem before by setting a z-index to -1, which hides the element, and if absolutely positioned also removes it from the static layout. You can actually transition z-index (though it doesn't really look like animate), therefore doesn't mess up the opacity animation.

This worked for me on my application, although I eventually had to use JavaScript to go ahead and set the display property from none to block because I eventually needed to use the fading element in a overflow:auto element, which when it wasn't hidden, created scroll bars at undesired times.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sure, there are workarounds (like the one I posted), what I like to know is if this is according to spec (point me to where), and I'm looking for nicer ways to implement it. I guess that negative z-index works since the item is placed behind the body, or? Anyway, I don't see how that helps. The code I have posted works, but it is weird if that is the way it should be implemented :S I simply don't understand why you can not animate from "display: none"