# font-awesome animation not working with display: none;

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

If I hide an element with `display: none;`, and then show it at a later time with `$(".fa-spin").show()` the `fa-spin` animation doesn't work.

Note that everything works properly if the element is not hidden in the beginning but is hidden later with:

```
$(".fa-spin").hide()
```

This is the `.fa-spin` implementation:

```
.fa-spin {
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fa-spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

Can you explain this behavior?

**I am asking the reason of this behavior, not workarounds.**

https://jsfiddle.net/md0ej7pt/

Comment: Can you explain why you want a non-visible element to animate?

Comment: It's a loader, it starts hidden and it has to be shown afterwards.

Comment: Set `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` instead of `display: none` if you want to animate element.

Comment: I am asking the reason, not workarounds. I know how to work that around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS transform doesn't work on inline elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/css-transform-doesnt-work-on-inline-elements)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`jQuery.show()` sets the `display` property to `inline` when called on the `i` element. According to WC3 documentation `inline` elements cannot be animated:

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/

> **Transformable element**
>
> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories: an
>   element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either
>   *a block-level or atomic inline-level element, or whose display property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group,
>   table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption* [CSS21]

To correct this, use Vallius's suggestion of setting display: `inline-block` instead of using `show()`, or wrap the element and hide the parent instead.

https://jsfiddle.net/359zLsdf/2/

```
<span class="coggy" style="display:none" ><i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin myCog " style="display:none"  aria-hidden="true"></i>

$(".coggy").show();

$(".myCog").css("display","inline-block");
```

Comment: The second part of your answer is the correct answer. What about removing the first part and making it more readable?

Answer (score 0):

You just want an explanation of the behavior?

From developer.mozilla.org:

In addition to the many different display box types, the value none lets you turn off the display of an element; when you use none, all descendant elements also have their display turned off. **The document is rendered as though the element doesn't exist in the document tree**.

Compared to the visibility property:

The visibility property can be used to **hide an element while leaving the space where it would have been**. It can also hide rows or columns of a table.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Why isn't the element rotating once it's shown?

Comment: Ahhhh, I'm sorry. I did not understand your question. It looks like you already have an answer tho!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(".fa-cog").css("display","inline-block");
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a similar question here;

[CSS transition on an initially hidden elemement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451328/css-transition-on-an-initially-hidden-elemement)

It appears as though there are work-arounds; like to start with a `z-index: -1` instead of `display:none`, or to start with the element transparent.